# Reszing an image so it fits inside a specific size canvas and keeps aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have some boxes that have the dimensions of `340 x 170` and users will be uploading images that need to be displayed into these boxes; however I'm not really sure how to go about resizing them so they don't lose aspect ratio and always fit in the box.

Requirements..

- Canvas should always be 340 x 170
- Image can't lose aspect ratio
- If the image has a greater width than height than it should be as wide as possible to 340px
- Ditto to the height
- Should always be able to see the whole image in the canvas

Normally you would just resize by the largest side, however this obviously won't work as then you will end up with a larger height than 170px if the height is close to the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really care about is the relationship between the image's aspect ratio and the canvas' aspect ratio.

Here's some self-explanatory code (would be glad to add explanation if needed):

```
var imgRatio = img.width / img.height; // Image aspect ratio
var canvasRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height; // Canvas aspect ratio

var resultImageH, resultImageW; // Variables that hold the result of the sizing algorithm

if(imgRatio < canvasRatio) {
    resultImageH = canvas.height;
    resultImageW = resultImageH * imgRatio;
}
else {
    resultImageW = canvas.width;
    resultImageH = resultImageW / imgRatio;
}
```

Comment: Just a question.... if the image is going to keep it's aspect ratio anyway, is it necessary to set the height? I ask because the current code I use to resize images only uses width to do it and if I have to pass in the height as well then I will have to change a lot of things around.

Comment: @Brett Yes, it is. As you might see above, there are two cases. **In the first case,** the height is the limiting dimension, so you fill all of the `canvas`' height, and then calculate the appropriate width using the image's aspect ratio. **In the second case,** the width is the limiting dimension, so you fill all of the `canvas`' width and then calculate the appropriate height.

Comment: You don't need *either* of the image's dimensions to calculate the new size; you do need its aspect ratio, however (plus the `canvas`' dimensions).

Comment: Well what I mean is.... can I just pass the resulting width to my resize function or do I need to pass the height as well? Because if this code keeps the aspect ratio then I shouldn't need to pass the height as the resize function should be able to calculate that itself based off the width I am giving it.

Comment: @Brett Ah, got it. Yep, the code keeps the aspect ratio; you can just pass the resulting width and then calculate the height.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way available with php it does the resizing while uploading , first the html file to add the photo will contain form

```
<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="picuploader.php">
<input name="imgFile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="ADD NEW PIC">
```

then you need a file name it for example resize.php contain this code

```
<?php
class thumbnail
{
var $img;

function thumbnail($imgfile)
{
    //detect image format
    $this->img["format"]=ereg_replace(".*\.(.*)$","\\1",$imgfile);
    $this->img["format"]=strtoupper($this->img["format"]);
    if ($this->img["format"]=="JPG" || $this->img["format"]=="JPEG") {
        //JPEG
        $this->img["format"]="JPEG";
        $this->img["src"] = ImageCreateFromJPEG ($imgfile);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="PNG") {
        //PNG
        $this->img["format"]="PNG";
        $this->img["src"] = ImageCreateFromPNG ($imgfile);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="GIF") {
        //GIF
        $this->img["format"]="GIF";
        $this->img["src"] = ImageCreateFromGIF ($imgfile);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="WBMP") {
        //WBMP
        $this->img["format"]="WBMP";
        $this->img["src"] = ImageCreateFromWBMP ($imgfile);
    } else {
        //DEFAULT
        //echo "Not a Supported File";
        exit();
    }
    @$this->img["imgWidth"] = imagesx($this->img["src"]);
    @$this->img["imgHeight"] = imagesy($this->img["src"]);
    //default quality jpeg
    $this->img["quality"]=200;
}

function size_height($size=150)
{
    //height
    $this->img["imgHeight_thumb"]=$size;
    @$this->img["imgWidth_thumb"] = ($this->img["imgHeight_thumb"]/$this->img["imgHeight"])*$this->img["imgWidth"];
}

function size_width($size=340)
{
    //width
    $this->img["imgWidth_thumb"]=$size;
    @$this->img["imgHeight_thumb"] = ($this->img["imgWidth_thumb"]/$this->img["imgWidth"])*$this->img["imgHeight"];
}

function size_auto($size=200)
{
    //size
    if ($this->img["imgWidth"]>=$this->img["imgHeight"]) {
        $this->img["imgWidth_thumb"]=$size;
        @$this->img["imgHeight_thumb"] = ($this->img["imgWidth_thumb"]/$this->img["imgWidth"])*$this->img["imgHeight"];
    } else {
        $this->img["imgHeight_thumb"]=$size;
        @$this->img["imgWidth_thumb"] = ($this->img["imgHeight_thumb"]/$this->img["imgHeight"])*$this->img["imgWidth"];
    }
}

function jpeg_quality($quality=200)
{
    //jpeg quality
    $this->img["quality"]=$quality;
}

function show()
{
    //show thumb
    @Header("Content-Type: image/".$this->img["format"]);

    /* change ImageCreateTrueColor to ImageCreate if your GD not supported ImageCreateTrueColor function*/
    $this->img["des"] = ImageCreateTrueColor($this->img["imgWidth_thumb"],$this->img["imgHeight_thumb"]);
        @imagecopyresized ($this->img["des"], $this->img["src"], 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->img["imgWidth_thumb"], $this->img["imgHeight_thumb"], $this->img["imgWidth"], $this->img["imgHeight"]);

    if ($this->img["format"]=="JPG" || $this->img["format"]=="JPEG") {
        //JPEG
        imageJPEG($this->img["des"],"",$this->img["quality"]);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="PNG") {
        //PNG
        imagePNG($this->img["des"]);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="GIF") {
        //GIF
        imageGIF($this->img["des"]);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="WBMP") {
        //WBMP
        imageWBMP($this->img["des"]);
    }
}

function save($save="")
{
    //save thumb
    if (empty($save)) $save=strtolower("./thumb.".$this->img["format"]);
    /* change ImageCreateTrueColor to ImageCreate if your GD not supported ImageCreateTrueColor function*/
    $this->img["des"] = ImageCreateTrueColor($this->img["imgWidth_thumb"],$this->img["imgHeight_thumb"]);
        @imagecopyresized ($this->img["des"], $this->img["src"], 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->img["imgWidth_thumb"], $this->img["imgHeight_thumb"], $this->img["imgWidth"], $this->img["imgHeight"]);

    if ($this->img["format"]=="JPG" || $this->img["format"]=="JPEG") {
        //JPEG
        imageJPEG($this->img["des"],"$save",$this->img["quality"]);
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="PNG") {
        //PNG
        imagePNG($this->img["des"],"$save");
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="GIF") {
        //GIF
        imageGIF($this->img["des"],"$save");
    } elseif ($this->img["format"]=="WBMP") {
        //WBMP
        imageWBMP($this->img["des"],"$save");
    }
}
}
?>
```

then finally the copy and resizing in the file picuploader.php as follow

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "uploading_pah";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir ."/". basename($_FILES['imgFile']['name']);
$fileSaved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
$upicThName = $uploaddir ."/TH_". basename($_FILES['imgFile']['name']);

        include_once("resize.php");
        $picTh = copy($uploadfile, $upicThName);
        $upicThName = $upicThName;
        $thumb=new thumbnail($upicThName); 
        $thumb->size_width(340);
        $thumb->save($upicThName); 
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($upicThName);
        if($height > 170)
        {
              $thumb->size_height(170);   
              $thumb->save($upicThName); 
        }

         unlink($uploadfile);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I converted Chris's answer to PHP :)